# Why can’t I send messages with emailJS when hiding my keys in .env?

Tags: reactjs, email, key

I am using emailJS to be able to send messages through a contact form to my email.
I am having issues to get this to work when hiding my keys in a .env file.

When printing out my keys like following, everything works and the email gets sent.

```
const serviceId = 'service_xxx'
const templateId = 'template_xxx'
const userId = 'user_xxx'
```

But when instead printing:

```
const serviceId = process.env.REACT_APP_SERVICE_ID
const templateId = process.env.REACT_APP_TEMPLATE_ID
const userId = process.env.REACT_APP_USER_ID
```

I get an error that looks like this:
[error_message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vf2Xu.png)

My .env file looks like this:

```
REACT_APP_SERVICE_ID = 'service_xxx'  
REACT_APP_TEMPLATE_ID = 'template_xxx'
REACT_APP_USER_ID = 'user_xxx'
```

Any ideas on what’s missing?